# Validate File input controls inside Grid view

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a GridView control, inside which I am having some Fileupload controls(number of controls varies),
For File uploading I have buttons with the file upload control inside GridView, after user uploads the file,he clicks on finish which is outside the GridView. I need to apply validation on clicking Finish that user must upload all files before clicking Finish.
The GridView is inside WizardControl and The Finish Button is the Finsihed button of Wizard

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="Grid1_RowCommand" CssClass="table">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="col-5" id="statdiv">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="Statement" CssClass="fieldheadingStyle"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="filestatement" runat="server" Width="98%" CssClass="filestat" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblstatement" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StatementFile") %>' CssClass="lblstat"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5" id="courtdiv">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Document" CssClass="fieldheadingStyle"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="doc" runat="server" Width="98%" CssClass="filedoc" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblcourtdoc" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocumentFile") %>' CssClass="lbldoc"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnuploadfiles" runat="server" CommandName="uploadfiles" Text="Upload" />
                </div>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

How can I validate all file controls on clicking Finished?

This is my finish button inside Wizard control

```
<FinishNavigationTemplate>
    <table class="WizardButtonRow" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <asp:Button ID="btnFinish" runat="server" Text="Finish" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="MoveComplete" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</FinishNavigationTemplate>
```

I have tried  this but its saying btnFinish not found

```
   $("#<%=btnFinish.ClientID%>").click(function(){
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity you have is the wizardcontrol. It only makes a section of the page available to the client therefore JS can only communicate with this particular visible section. A way round is to use JS based wizard syntax that will only show one section at a time. You can use div for each section and make inactive ones hidden. This will make JS to have access to all the elements because they are in still in the DOM.

In addition, note the generated html tags for the fileupload controls matter after you view the page in a browser. This will help in understanding your page rendering and it can help in the sequence of the id used for each control so you can use the proper id and select each and check if it has a file.

If you are using .NET framework 4.0 (vs2010) and above, you can set clientidmode=static with asp.net control tag. This will ensure that the id you specified is the rendered id for html. With this you can select btnfinish with this

```
  $('#btnfinish').click(function(){

   });
```

Alternatively, with JQuery you can set same cssclass for the file upload (only) in the gridview template. Once this is done, you may then select all elements with the class. This will return the collection of the fileupload controls and this can be cycled through with 'each' function in Jquery.

```
 $('.fileuploadClass').each(function(){ //cycle through all file upload with specified cssclass
   if ($(this).val()==''){ //check of it has a file
         alert('select file');
         return;
      }
 });
```